# When parsing the typeAliases tag with package as a subtag in the mybatis framework, a parsing error occurs. I used jdk9 as a development environment

Tags: mybatis, java-9

**Environment Configure**

- jdk9
- mybatis v3.5.4
- MacOS

**Description**

> When I was studying `Mybatis`, I encountered confusing questions. The configuration in question is as follows:
>
> ```xml
> <configuration>
>    <typeAliases>
>       <package name="com.xxx.entity" />
>    </typeAliases>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> The code to start mybatis is as follows:
>
> ```java
> // the var of CONFIG_LOCATION is the url for mybatis configure
> Reader config = Resources.getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_LOCATION);
> SqlSessionFactory sqlSessioinFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(config);
> ```
>
> When parsing the `typeAliases` tag, if the subtag is `package`, an exception will be thrown:
>
> ```
> Error building SqlSession.
> The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration
> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Nul character not allowed: com/akamonk/ruixun/entity/Cart.class/����5+  "  #  $  %
>     at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
>     at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:80)
>     at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:64)
>     at s2.project/com.akamonk.ruixun.listener.ContextLoader.initContext(ContextLoader.java:39)
>     at s2.project/com.akamonk.ruixun.listener.ContextLoader.main(ContextLoader.java:59)
> Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Nul character not allowed: com/akamonk/ruixun/entity/Cart.class/����5+  "  #  $  %
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:121)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parse(XMLConfigBuilder.java:98)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:78)
> ... 3 more
> Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Nul character not allowed: com/akamonk/ruixun/entity/Cart.class/����5+ "  #  $  %
>      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.checkNotNul(UnixPath.java:91)
>      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:81)
>      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:69)
>      at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.module.Resources.toSafeFilePath(Resources.java:138)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.module.Resources.toFilePath(Resources.java:97)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferences$ExplodedModuleReader.find(ModuleReferences.java:384)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$2.run(BuiltinClassLoader.java:408)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$2.run(BuiltinClassLoader.java:403)
>      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findMiscResource(BuiltinClassLoader.java:402)
>      at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findResources(BuiltinClassLoader.java:333)
>      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1457)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.io.VFS.getResources(VFS.java:171)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.io.DefaultVFS.list(DefaultVFS.java:105)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.io.DefaultVFS.list(DefaultVFS.java:153)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.io.VFS.list(VFS.java:200)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.io.ResolverUtil.find(ResolverUtil.java:220)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.registerAliases(TypeAliasRegistry.java:130)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.registerAliases(TypeAliasRegistry.java:125)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.typeAliasesElement(XMLConfigBuilder.java:164)
>      at org.mybatis@3.5.4/org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.parseConfiguration(XMLConfigBuilder.java:109) 
> ... 5 more
> ```
>
> At this time, the content of module-info.java is as follows
>
> ```java
> open module mybatis.test {
>   requires org.mybatis;
>   requires java.sql;
> }
> ```
>
> There is a strange phenomenon, when I remove the module-info.java from the project, mybatis will not have problems when parsing `typeAliases`.Therefore, my bold guess is caused by JDK9. But I don't know how to solve it and the specific cause of the problem

Comment: There seems to be a file whose name contains a null character somewhere in the project directory. Moving the file out of the project directory or removing the null character from the filename should fix the problem. According to the error message, the name of the file contains `5+ "  #  $  %`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think it is not due to this reason. When I was debugging the code, I found that when searching for the class under the package path represented by the `package` tag, mybatis also read the contents of the `.class` file, and then caused an `InvalidPathException`. The specific code is in **DefaultVFS#list(URL url, String path)**.

Comment: MyBatis does not read the content of `.class` files. Please see this [comment](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/mybatis-3.5.4/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/io/DefaultVFS.java#L90-L95). It is basically reading a list of files.

Comment: As the description says, `To work around that, as each line is read, try to look it up via the class loader as a child of the current resource.` When the resource path read represents a directory, of course, the file list is read. When reading a file, in order to confirm whether it is a directory, it will read each line in the file, and use the content of each line as a sub-resource of the current resource and try to load it.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, when "com/akamonk/ruixun/entity/Cart.class" is read, each line of the file will be read, the first line reading from Cart.class is “����5+ "# $ %”.  However, in JDK9, when there is module-info.java, `getResources("com/akamonk/ruixun/entity/Cart.class/����5+ "# $ %")` does not return empty, but directly throws An exception occurred-InvalidPathException. If I remove `module-info.java` from the project, everything will become normal.

Comment: Or do I have any misunderstanding about this？

Comment: You might be right. Could you file a bug report on the [tracker](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/new)? We should catch and ignore the `InvalidPathException`, I guess.

Comment: What puzzles me most is that when module-info.java is removed, no exception is thrown, and it runs normally

Comment: I cannot be certain from the provided information, but I know that [ClassLoader#getResoruce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) behaves differently under JPMS. I'd be curious to know if you find out the reason. :)

Comment: I found that it was caused by the `Named Module`. `ClassLoader#getResource` will eventually be handed over to `BuiltinClassLoader#findResource `to load the resource. _step1:_ If the resource is in the module's package, the loading of the resource is handed over to the loader of the module; or. _step2_: try to load the resource from the module that defined in this loader.  If it is still not found, _step3_: find it from the classpath. The custom `Named Module` (mybatis.test) will be loaded by AppClassLoader.

Comment: In step2, the module is traversed until the module name is mybatis.test. At this time, `ExplodedModuleReader#find` looks for the specified resource in the module. Because the resource path contains illegal characters, it is forced to throw an exception. I'm not familiar with JPMS, the conclusion above is obtained by debugging the code